# Updating wrong image using PHP MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, session

I am trying to allow admin to update photos of advertisements. I've managed to get the update part working, but it keeps updating the wrong advertisement (the first one in the database). I think it might not be registering the ID of the one I want to update when it is submitting to the database but I can't see what I have done wrong. I've used this code before for a profile picture update, but i'm guessing it's the session that is making it do this?

Here is my adupload.php code

```
<?php
$id=$_POST['id'];

 $target_dir = "uploads/";
 $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
 $uploadOk = 1;
 $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

 // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
 if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
echo "<b><center>The file uploaded was not an image!<br><center><a    
href=\"update_ad.php?id=$id\">Go back here!</a>";

    $uploadOk = 0;
}
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
     echo "<b><center>Sorry, this image already exists! <br><center><a   
href=\"update_ad.php?id=$id\">Go back here!</a>";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 50000000) {
     echo "<b><center>Sorry, your image is too large.<br><center><a      
href=\"update_ad.php?id=$id\">Go back here!</a>";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType 
!= "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
 echo "<b><center>Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.<br>  
<center><a href=\"update_ad.php?id=$id\">Go back here!</a>";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "<b><center>Sorry your picture was not uploaded.<br><center><a 
href=\"update_ad.php?id=$id\">Go back here!</a>";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],  
$target_file)) {
    echo "<center>Your profile picture ". basename(   
$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded! <br><center><a   
href=\"admin.php\">Go back to the admin area</a>";


    $sql = "UPDATE advertisement SET imageName='$target_file' WHERE  
id=$id";
    mysqli_query($mysqli_conn, $sql);


} else {
    print "<b><center>An error occurred when uploading your picture<br> 
<center><a href=\"update_ad.php?id=$id\">Go back here!</a>";
}
}
?>
```

Here is a snippet of update_ad.php

```
$id = $_GET['id'] ;  //Get the primary key passed

$query = "SELECT * FROM advertisement WHERE id = '$id' "; 

//if error in query, display
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli_conn, $query)  or exit ("Error in query:    
$query. ".mysqli_error()); 

//see if any rows were returned 
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {  // yes then display Form 

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); //then fetch the row 

?> 

<table border= "3" style="width:100%;margin:auto">
<form action = 'update_ad_action.php' method="POST"> 
<tr><td>ID:</td><td><input  readonly="yes" name="id" type="text" value=<?  
php echo $id; ?> size="3" ></td></tr>
<tr><td>Title:</td><td><input type="text" name="title" value=<?php echo  
$row["title"] ?> ></td></tr>
<tr><td>Description:</td><td><input type="text" name="description" value=    
<?php echo $row["description"] ?> ></td></tr>
<tr><td>From-date:</td><td><input type="text" name="from_date" value=<?
php echo $row["from_date"] ?> ></td></tr> 
<tr><td>To-date:</td><td><input type="text" name="to_date" value=<?php 
echo $row["to_date"] ?> ></td></tr>
<tr><td>Pets:</td><td><select name="pets" id="pets"> 
                <option value="0">Yes</option>
                <option value="1">No</option></td></tr>
<tr><td>Location:</td><td><input type="text" name="location" value=<?php 
echo $row["location"] ?> ></td></tr>
<tr><td>Picture</td><td><img src=" <?php echo $row['imageName'] ?>" 
alt="No picture uploaded" width="200" height ="200" ></td></tr>
<tr><th colspan="2"><center><input class="button button-primary" 
type="Submit" value="Submit"/>&nbsp<input class="button button-primary"   
type="reset" value="Clear"/></center></th></tr>
</form> 
</table>
<br>
<table border= "3" style="width:100%;margin:auto">
<form action="adupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<tr><td>Want to change your picture?</td><td>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>">
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" required></td>    
</tr>
<tr><th colspan="2"><center><input class="button button-primary" 
type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit"></center></th></tr>
</form></table>
```

update_ad_action.php

```
<?php require 'config/init.php' ;

$id = $_POST['id']; //get id passed

$errorString = ""; //string to collect errors if found
 $title = trim($_POST["title"]); //trim white spaces

if (empty($title)) { 

 $errorString = $errorString."<br><center>Please enter a title. 
 </center>";  //if empty, error added to error string

 //remove any slashes that are automatically added, strip tags and 
 disable html tags from having any affect
 $title = htmlentities(strip_tags($title));

 }

 $description = trim($_POST["description"]); 

 if (empty($description)) { 

  $errorString = $errorString."<br><center>Please enter a description.<  
 </center>"; //if empty, error added to error string

 //remove any slashes that are automatically added, strip tags and 
disable html tags from having any affect
$title = htmlentities(strip_tags($description));

 }

$from_date = trim($_POST["from_date"]); 

if (empty($from_date)) { 

$errorString = $errorString."<br><center>Please enter a from date.
</center>"; //if empty, error added to error string

//remove any slashes that are automatically added, strip tags and disable 
html tags from having any affect
$title = htmlentities(strip_tags($from_date));

}

$to_date = trim($_POST["to_date"]); 

if (empty($to_date)) { 

$errorString = $errorString."<br><center>Please enter a to date.
</center>"; //if empty, error added to error string

//remove any slashes that are automatically added, strip tags and disable 
html tags from having any affect
$title = htmlentities(strip_tags($to_date));

}

$location = trim($_POST["location"]); 

if (empty($location)) { 

$errorString = $errorString."<br><center>Please enter a location</center> 
"; //if empty, error added to error string

//remove any slashes that are automatically added, strip tags and disable 
html tags from having any affect
$title = htmlentities(strip_tags($location));

}   



// check if there were any errors

if (empty($errorString)) {//No errors, update the data


//query to update data
$query = "UPDATE user SET title = '$title', description = '$description',   
from_date = '$from_date', to_date = '$to_date', location = '$location' 
WHERE id = '$id'";

 $result = mysqli_query($mysqli_conn, $query);

//if there was a problem - get the error message and go back

if (mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli_conn) < 0) {

echo "There were errors :<br>" . mysql_error();

echo $query;

exit ;

} else { //locate back to profile if updated

header("Location: admin.php");

}

} else {//There were errors

print '<b><center>There were errors<br>' . $errorString . "<center><a    
href=\"update_ad.php?id=$id\">Go back here!</a>";
}
?>
```

Comment: action = 'update_ad_action.php' this page is different than that you have written in question

Comment: @SantoshRamKunjir update_ad_action.php is not used for the image form. The image form is adupload.php

Comment: Print `$id` and `$target_file` just before executing the query. Then try to run the query manually in your MySQL Client (phpMyAdmin, e.g.). What is the result?

Comment: @OrioldelRio I'm not quite sure now to do this, I'm beginner to PHP at the moment

Comment: @Jess Go to `mysqli_query($mysqli_conn, $sql)`. In the previous line, insert `die($sql)`. Then upload an image. Does it looks like the correct query? Can you run it manually on your MySQL?

Comment: I also wonder where are you setting `$_SESSION['id']`. The form might be getting a wrong ID.

Comment: @OrioldelRio hm... **UPDATE advertisement SET imageName='uploads/2015-10-04 19.59.41.jpg' WHERE id='1'** appears! So somewhere I'm doing something wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID in your `$_SESSION['id']` is likely to be wrong and thus you are sending always the same ID.

If you want to get the ID passed by URL (?id=1337), use `<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>` in the form instead of `$_SESSION`.

Comment: ha ha @Oriol del Rio - already posted that :)) - just got in ahead of you ")

Comment: How can I change this?

Comment: @gavgrif Well, let him decide if this is definitely the correct answer. Then he will have to decide who has been more helpful and who has been shooting while blindfolded.

Comment: @Jess Somewhere you are initializing a session with `session_start()` and you are setting an ID into `$_SESSION`. Take a look to this part and think if you are passing the ID to the form in a correct way.

Comment: @OrioldelRio   I currently have a user logged in, is this creating the problem? However, the login details are nothing to do with the advert table

Comment: @Jess Do you want to take the ID passed by URL? Then use `<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>` in the form instead of `$_SESSION`.

Comment: @Oriol del Rio - sorry - but I also posted that too - but since the OP is already assigning "$id = $_GET['id'] " - I used $id in my post. at least we are thinking along the same lines :)

Comment: Bit of an idiot moment there.. that was all it took lol @OrioldelRio. Thanks for your patience xD

Comment: @Oriol del Rio - well played ! you win! :)))

Comment: @Jess You're welcome. Next time try to simplify the problem as much as you can before posting a question. People doesn't like these huge code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

where are you setting $_SESSION['id'] = $id? - if you are not setting that then this input will have no value.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>">
```

you could change it to:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

also I am not loving the space in the name you posted

```
imageName='uploads/2015-10-04 19.59.41.jpg'
```

should really be with a hyphen or an underscore.:

```
 imageName='uploads/2015-10-04_19.59.41.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

you need `' '` around the variable in your update query in your adupload.php code:

```
    $sql = "UPDATE advertisement SET imageName='$target_file' WHERE  
id=$id";
```

should be

```
    $sql = "UPDATE advertisement SET imageName='$target_file' WHERE  
id='$id'";
```

Comment: MySQL will compensate for it; quotes aren't needed.